# Can I expect a delay if I am showing the s3 content in website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Since s3 is eventually consistent, in how much time will the data become consistent. If my user uploads some media, and I if I have to show the same content in website, can i expect a scenario where others users might not see the content in website for some time, and some users can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its eventually consistent, but in my experience that usually means under a few seconds - so yes it's possible, but only for a very,very small amount of time

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very quick. Quick enough that any limitations to update speed would not be caused by s3. I host a static website in s3, and I can upload/update a file and see the contents in less than 1 second (i.e. refresh the page as fast as I can).